# How to add a user to django site, when using remote auth backend?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-users

I am using Django for a site, and have a remote auth backend setup. Is there a way In which I can create a new user and give them permissions before they login to the site? I know I can add users through the admin page or directly through the database, but since I do not know the new users password, I am not sure if the system will see them as the same user

I have tried using the admin page, but it says I need to enter a password

I would like to be able to add users to the system before they logon, and give them permissions, so that when they logon they are not redirected to my unauthorized page. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from your question, You can create the user by using the

*[`python manage.py createsuperuser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial02/#creating-an-admin-user)*

which will create the superuser and later on you can edit on this user and can give your permissions.